# Android soft keyboard not staying hidden

Tags: android

I have this Android application I am trying to work on, but when I try to keep the soft keyboard hidden from the screen (the hardware includes a keyboard) for this particular alert dialog, it does not stay hidden, despite the fact that I am following the same setup as a previous alert dialog, that does work.

The following function, enterItem, functions exactly as I am expecting it to, which means it does not bring up the soft keyboard when someone uses the hardware to type in data.

```
public void enterItem() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_keyin_number_field, null);
    final EditText userInputDialogEditText = viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.keyInNumber);
    userInputDialogEditText.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    builder
            .setTitle(reason.getDescription())
            .setMessage("Enter/Scan Item: ")
            .setView(viewInflated)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String input = userInputDialogEditText.getText().toString();
                    if (StringUtils.isNotNullOrEmpty(input)) {
                        new AsyncVerifyItemWS().execute(input);
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });//end builder

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    userInputDialogEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED || actionId ==  EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    userInputDialogEditText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
}
```

This function, however, does *not* function as I expect it to. The second I begin to type on the hardware keyboard, the soft keyboard pops up and does not go away with any subsequent clicks.

```
public void enterComment(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_text_area_field, null);
    final EditText userInputDialogEditText = viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.keyInText);
    userInputDialogEditText.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.lightGrey));

    builder
            .setTitle(reason.getDescription())
            .setMessage("Enter Comment: ")
            .setView(viewInflated)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    comments = userInputDialogEditText.getText().toString();
                    //move on...
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //move on...
                }
            });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    userInputDialogEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED || actionId ==  EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    userInputDialogEditText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
}
```

In addition to using `setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false)` I have also tried to use `userInputDialogEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);` as well as the following function:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if (imm != null) {
     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

The input method manager (placed in `onEditorAction()` does not change anything, and while using `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)` does work, it removes the blinking position bar on the screen.

I am very new to Android development and nobody that I work with seems to have any ideas how to make this work, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after figuring out a better way to research my issue. I don't like this answer, personally. It doesn't make sense to me that the last EditText widget doesn't work the same way as the other ones in the Activity do, but by adding an `OnKeyListener()` to the object, I can fully prevent the soft keyboard from appearing on the screen. There *is* still a flashing icon on the bottom of the screen with every click, but the soft keyboard remains hidden.

```
userInputDialogEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```